# Converting Kodak PCD Files to TIF?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a few dozen Kodak CD-ROMs (with a few thousand photo scans) from the early 2000s that contain PCD files.

I want to convert them to a maximum quality file (TIF?) for further processing in Photoshop.

It's easy to convert them to ".tif":

convert img0001.pcd img0001.tif

But I get crazy (inverted?) colors.

I've tried:

convert -colorspace rgb img0001.pcd img0001.tif

and have MUCh better results, however, the colors and blacks are very crushed, and the images are VERY dark.

What's the current best practice for reviving these old scans with decent histograms?

Thank you.

Comment: Try opening your PCD files in Irfanview or PSPro instead. I have never encountered the problem that you describe with Kodak PCD files so I suspect that the decoder you are using does not honour the gamma correction. I was a very early adopter of that format. I thought Photoshop could also decode them natively (at least my ancient version 5 could). PNG might also be worth a try in case that workflow can do any better.

Comment: Your chances of getting a good answer might improve considerably if you shared an image or two - maybe Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Note that saving to uncompressed TIFF as above ***may*** cause needlessly large files. Depending on the image content and bit-depth, you ***may*** find you get smaller files of identical quality by adding either `-compress zip` or `-compress lzw`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a colourspace that sets the gamma correctly for display on your device. Try:

```
convert -colorspace sRGB img0001.pcd img0001.tif
```

You might also be interested in getting images larger than the base 512 × 768 size. In that case you can add a suffix to extract the larger versions. Depending on what kind of Photo CD you have, the largest is either `5` or `6`.

```
convert -colorspace sRGB 'img0001.pcd[5]' img0001.tif
```

---

I used `BlownJohn.pcd` from https://sembiance.com/fileFormatSamples/image/pcd/ for testing, in case anyone's curious.

Comment: Nice answer. Note that the command and order of parameters changed with v7 ImageMagick several years back. Nowadays it would be `magick 'image001.pcd[5]' -colorspace sRGB result.tif`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

I used the sample PCD files shown above and re-processed them with "-colorspace sRGB" instead of a leading '-colorspace rgb" and the images look way more normal than my previous attempts.

This Works:

```
convert charmouth2.pcd[6] -colorspace sRGB charmouth2.tif
```

This provides the very dark results:

```
convert -colorspace rgb charmouth2.pcd[6] charmouth2.tif
```

Thank you!

Comment: Huh? Why did you use someone else's samples instead of your own files? Surely you want to process your own samples?

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote @AkselA 's answer if it was useful to you.